# Project Euler #12

Tags: ruby

12 The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:

1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...

Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

- 1: 1
- 3: 1,3
- 6: 1,2,3,6
- 10: 1,2,5,10
- 15: 1,3,5,15
- 21: 1,3,7,21
- 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28

We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.

What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

define a method that lists the factors of a number
iterate through the sequence til a triangle is found with 500 factors 
return the number that has 500 factors
if factors.count == 500

```
def factors(num)
  current_number = 1 
  factors_list= []
  while current_number <= num
    if is_factor(num,current_number)
      factors_list << current_number
    end
    current_number += 1 
  end
  return factors_list
end

def is_factor(big,small)
  if big % small == 0 
    return true 
  else 
    false 
  end
end     

def big_triangle(num) #500
  triangles = [1]
  natural_numbers = 1
  while factors(natural_numbers).count != num 
    triangles << natural_numbers
    natural_numbers += 1     
  end
  triangles.select { |n| factors(n).count == num }
end
```

Comment: I've checked the problem definition and it is not necessary to store all the triangle numbers. It is only required to return the first triangle number whose  number of divisor is over 500. Are you trying to achieve that right??

Comment: Your last two sentences are contradictory. The first states that you want the first triangle number with more than 500 factors, which is how the problem is normally stated. The second says you want the first triangle number with exactly 500 factors (though you may mean more than 500).  I'm don't know if there is a triangle number with exactly 500 factors, and if there is, how long it would take to find it.

Answer (score 1):

We should of course make use of relevant methods that Ruby provides. In this case one such (class) method is [Prime::prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division). For example,

```
require 'prime'

Prime.prime_division(2106)
  #=> [[2, 1], [3, 4], [13, 1]]
```

This tells us that 2106 has primes `2`, `3`, and `13`, and that

```
2**1 * 3**4 * 13**1
  #=> 2106
```

How many factors does `2106` have? Each factor is of the form

```
2**a * 3**b * 13**c
```

where `0 <= a <= 1`, `0 <= b <= 4`, `0 <= c <= 1`. This includes `a = b = c = 0`, the factor being `1` and `a, b, c = 1, 4, 1`, the factor being `2106`. The number of factors therefore equals

```
(1+1) * (4+1) * (1+1)
  #=> 20
```

That is, for each number of times `2` is included (`0` or `1`), `3` can be included between `0` and `4` times, and for each of those 10 pairs, `13` can be included `0` or `1` times.

To take a simpler example, consider the triangle number `45`:

```
Prime.prime_division(45)
  #=> [[3, 2], [5, 1]]
```

The number of factors is therefore

```
(2+1) * (1 + 1)
  #=> 6
```

Those factors are

```
3**0 * 5**0 #=>  1
3**0 * 5**1 #=>  5 
3**1 * 5**0 #=>  3 
3**1 * 5**1 #=> 15 
3**2 * 5**0 #=>  9 
3**2 * 5**1 #=> 45
```

We can therefore write

```
def nbr_factors(n)
  Prime.prime_division(n).reduce(1){ |t,(_,m)| t * (m+1) }
end

nbr_factors(2106)
  #=> 20
nbr_factors(45)
  #=> 6
```

The desired result may now be obtained quite easily.

```
def first_triangle_nbr_with_min_nbr_divisors(min_nbr_divisors)
  tri = 0
  1.step.each do |i|
    tri += i
    break tri if nbr_factors(tri) >= min_nbr_divisors
  end
end

first_triangle_nbr_with_min_nbr_divisors   6 #=>         28
first_triangle_nbr_with_min_nbr_divisors  20 #=>        528
first_triangle_nbr_with_min_nbr_divisors 501 #=> 76_576_500
```

The last few calculations for the last example are as follows.

```
...
i=12372, tri=76539378, nbr_factors(tri)=16
i=12373, tri=76551751, nbr_factors(tri)=8
i=12374, tri=76564125, nbr_factors(tri)=96
i=12375, tri=76576500, nbr_factors(tri)=576
```

Comment: Nice use of the Prime class